# Comparsion in cuda

Tags: cuda, compare

I have to compare two floating point arrays(a,b)in CUDA such that
`if a > b then a = a/a ; else a = 0`.

Please tell the correct way and the syntax to call this.

Comment: what does a = a/a mean?  Isn't that just saying a = 1 ?

Comment: yes a=a/a means 1,, basically if a[i]>b[i],, i wants to return the value 1 otherwise 0 and this i wants to repeat for all the index values(say 20)

Comment: sir, basically i am using CUFFT lib. in that i got two outputs, that i have to compare for 4096 index values. so plz guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. I'm simplifying my usual cuda error checking for brevity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DSIZE 10000
#define nTPB 512

__global__ void cmp(float *a, float *b, int size){
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < size)
    a[idx]=(a[idx] > b[idx])?1.0f:0.0f;  // could also be: ?(a[idx]/a[idx]):0;
}

int main() {
  cudaError_t err;
  float *h_a, *h_b, *d_a, *d_b;
  h_a = (float *)malloc(DSIZE*sizeof(float));
  if (h_a == 0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return 1;}
  h_b = (float *)malloc(DSIZE*sizeof(float));
  if (h_b == 0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return 1;}
  for (int i=0; i< DSIZE; i++){
    h_a[i] = 10.0f;
    h_b[i] = (float)i;}
  err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, DSIZE*sizeof(float));
  if (err != cudaSuccess) {printf("cuda fail\n"); return 1;}
  err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, DSIZE*sizeof(float));
  if (err != cudaSuccess) {printf("cuda fail\n"); return 1;}
  err = cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, DSIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if (err != cudaSuccess) {printf("cuda fail\n"); return 1;}
  err = cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, DSIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if (err != cudaSuccess) {printf("cuda fail\n"); return 1;}

  cmp<<<(DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB>>>(d_a, d_b, DSIZE);
  err=cudaMemcpy(h_a, d_a, DSIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  if (err != cudaSuccess) {printf("cuda fail\n"); return 1;}
  for (int i=0; i< 20; i++)
    printf("h_a[%d] = %f\n", i, h_a[i]);
  return 0;
}
```